# Difference between @OneToMany and @ElementCollection?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

What is the difference between using a `@OneToMany` and `@ElementCollection` annotation since both work on the one-to-many relationship?

Comment: In a nutshell, @ElementCollection is used when the existence of the child-entity is meaningless without the parent entity, IOW, whenever a parent entity is removed, your children will also be...

Comment: I believe it is NOT the child Entity, it is Value Type/Value Object which is embedded and whose existence is meaning less without the main Entity in which it is contained.

Comment: agree with @CuriousMind, in JPA an 'Entity'  has its own lifecycle.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

I believe `@ElementCollection` is mainly for mapping non-entities (embeddable or basic) while `@OneToMany` is used to map entities. So which one to use depend on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks Peder for the answer! You've a valid point there since @OneToMany can only relate entities.

Answer (score 205):

`ElementCollection` is a standard JPA annotation, which is now preferred over the proprietary Hibernate annotation `CollectionOfElements`.

It means that the collection is not a collection of entities, but a collection of simple types (Strings, etc.) or a collection of embeddable elements (class annotated with `@Embeddable`).

It also means that the elements are completely owned by the containing entities: they're modified when the entity is modified, deleted when the entity is deleted, etc. They can't have their own lifecycle.

Comment: ... and you cannot query them on their own.

Answer (score 97):

`@ElementCollection` allows you to simplify code when you want to implement one-to-many relationship with simple or embedded type. For instance in JPA 1.0 when you wanted to have a one-to-many relationship to a list of `String`s, you had to create a simple entity POJO (`StringWrapper`) containing only primary key and the `String` in question:

```
@OneToMany
private Collection<StringWrapper> strings;

//...

public class StringWrapper {
  @Id
  private int id;

  private String string;
}
```

With JPA 2.0 you can simply write:

```
@ElementCollection
private Collection<String> strings;
```

Simpler, isn't it? Note that you can still control the table and column names using `@CollectionTable` annotation.

### See also:

- [Java Persistence/ElementCollection](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection)

Answer (score 8):

**Basic or Embedded**: @ElementCollection
**Entities**: @OneToMany or @ManyToMany

@ElementCollection:

- the relation is managed (only) by the entity in which the relation is defined
- table contains id reference to the owning entity plus basic or embedded attributes

@OneToMany / @ManyToMany:

- can also be managed by the other entity
- join table or column(s) typically contains id references only

Answer (score 3):

## @ElementCollection

This annotation will be applied when there is a relation with non-entity and these associations relation was **HAS-A**. Every collection is created with a table and gets relation by *Foreign Key*.

There are two types of element collections

- Index (List, Map)
- Non-Index (Set)

**Index**: The index type collection has a table with 3 columns they are

- Key Column (Foriegn Key)
- Index Column (Position of data in collection)
- Element Column (Data)

**Non-Index**: The Non-Index type collection has a table with 2 columns they are

- Key Column
- Element Column

*Note*: Here it won't have any index column because, Since a **SET** doesn’t retain the insertion order.

## Multiplicity

This is a way to implement the HAS-A relation between two entities and the cardinality ratio depends on their relation.

Answer (score 1):

`@ElementCollection` marks a collection. This does not necessarily mean that this collection references a 1-n join.

Comment: So what exactly is the purpose of @ElementCollection?

Answer (score 1):

ElementCollection can override the mappings, or table for their collection, so you can have multiple entities reference the same Embeddable class, but have each store their dependent objects in a separate table.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ElementCollection replace for you use @OneToMany. Example you can have one Project in many versions.

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="versions",
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="projectID"))
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@JoinColumn(name="version",nullable = false)
private Set<String> versions;
```

You also can use @ElementCollection in mapping OGM for array in one collection.

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<String> researchAreas;
```