# How to specify JPA join column names?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Does anyone know how to specify a specific column name with the following simple example?

```
@Entity
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private final Integer id;

    ...
}

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private final Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_roles" joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")})
    private final Set<Role> roles;

    ...
}
```

This frustratingly results in a table called "user_roles" and field names: "user_id" and "roles_id".

Why "roles_id" and not "role_id", and how can I change this to "role_id"?

For what it's worth I use JPA 2.0, MySQL and Hibernate. The data I want to add is added correctly, so this is just a matter of taste.

Edit:

The following might be a little bit JPA 1.0'ish, but it works as required.

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use following annotaion in `User` Entity:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "user_roles")
@Column(name = "role_id")
private Set<Role> roles;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that also, but nothing changes. It still uses "roles_id" unfortunately.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'roles_id' in 'field list'

Comment: What JPA version you are using?

Comment: If you generate schema from java code, than use drop-and-create generation type or manually drop the table.

Comment: JPA version 2.0 (hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar)

Comment: When I specify hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create as a property in persistence.xml I get the following table created for me:

CREATE TABLE `user_roles` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `roles_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_amwlmdeik2qdnksxgd566knop` (`roles_id`),
  KEY `FK_amwlmdeik2qdnksxgd566knop` (`roles_id`),
  KEY `FK_g1uebn6mqk9qiaw45vnacmyo2` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_g1uebn6mqk9qiaw45vnacmyo2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_amwlmdeik2qdnksxgd566knop` FOREIGN KEY (`roles_id`) REFERENCES `role` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: I have tested it with JPA 2.1. I will try latter with hibernate.

Comment: I do notice that when I change the name of the Set to "role" instead of "roles", then indeed the field name IS "role_id" and not "roles_id". So, it is using the variable name by default, but how to override this. Maybe I'm being picky, but logically the variable should be called "roles" and the field name "role_id". Hmmmm.

Answer (score 0):

From Hibernate reference:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/

Use the following annotation in your **User** entity:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="user_roles", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"))
@Column(name="role_id")
public Set<Role> getRoles() { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, will check this. The only difference to the above being that the annotations are on the 'getter' (given that we already added the @Column part which didn't change things unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in @ElementCollection. It seems it is more suitable for simple types. I'll stick with the @ManyToMany annotation as specified in my edit to the question. It seems this topic has been addressed in another way before: [Difference between @OneToMany and @ElementCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969059/difference-between-onetomany-and-elementcollection)

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is wrong. Role is an entity but @ElementCollection should be used with basic types or Embeddables.

If Role is an @Entity then I would suggest you want a @ManytoMany with at @JoinTable spcifying the join and inverse join columns

Otherwise you can make Role Embeddable and use @ElementCollection which will give you a one to many with a user_roles table something like user_id, role_name.

Either of these will generate your schema as specified.

Comment: Thanks, I already came to that conclusion in my answer above.