# Getting an SQL error when trying to retrieve an ElementCollection using Spring data

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I have an entity called `AffiliateLink` that has an elementcollection set called `keywords`. I am trying to retrieve a subset of fields from `AffiliateLink` that includes the `keywords` field. For this i've made this method in my `AffiliateLinkDao`.

```
@Query("SELECT new DTOs.EntityDTOs.AffiliateLinkUpdateDTO(s.affiliateUrl, s.title, s.description, s.productValue, s.general, s.rank, s.seedId, s.plantClimbs, s.spicy, s.teaPlant, s.keywords) FROM AffiliateLink s WHERE s.id = :id")
public AffiliateLinkUpdateDTO getAffiliateLinkDetailsById(@Param("id") long id);
```

As you can see i'm using the constructor of a DTO object called `AffiliateLinkUpdateDTO` to get the required fields. This object extends another class called `AffiliateLinkCreateDTO` because they both share similar fields The SQL syntax error is somehow caused by s.keywords, the error message goes:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as col_10_0_
>   from AffiliateLink affiliatel0_ inner join affiliate_keywords keywo'
>   at line 1

For some reason it is trying to do an `inner join`  on `affiliate_keywords keywo` while the `Collection table` is named `affiliate_keywords`. I don't know why it is doing that and i was wondering if anyone could give me a few pointers on what i might be doing wrong that is causing this error. Here are the classes used:

The `AffiliateLink` class:

```
@Entity
public class AffiliateLink implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "ID_GENERATOR")
    private Long id;

    @URL
    private String affiliateUrl;

    @URL
    private String affiliateImageUrl;

    private String title;

    private String description;

    private Double productValue;

    private boolean general;

    private byte rank;

    private boolean linkBroken;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean plantClimbs;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean spicy;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean teaPlant;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(updatable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date creationDate;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "affiliate_keywords", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "affiliate_id"))
    @Column(name = "keywords")
    private Set<String> keywords;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "affiliateLinks")
    private Set<SeedRecord> seedRecords = new HashSet<>();

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private LocalizedStorefront localizedStorefront;

    private long seedId;
```

The `AffiliateLinkUpdateDTO` class:

```
public class AffiliateLinkUpdateDTO extends AffiliateLinkCreateDTO {
    @NotNull
    private long affiliateId;

    private String affiliateImageUrl;

    public AffiliateLinkUpdateDTO() {
    }

    public AffiliateLinkUpdateDTO(String affiliateUrl, String title, String description, Double productValue, Boolean general, Byte rank, Long seedId, Boolean plantClimbs,
                              Boolean spicy, Boolean teaPlant, Set<String> keywords){
        super(affiliateUrl, title, description, productValue, general, rank, seedId, plantClimbs, spicy, teaPlant, keywords);
        this.affiliateId = affiliateId;
        this.affiliateImageUrl = affiliateImageUrl;
    }
```

The `AffiliateLinkCreateDTO` class that is extended by the UpdateDTO class

```
public class AffiliateLinkCreateDTO {

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = "http?://.+")
    private String affiliateUrl;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min=2, max=14)
    private String title;
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min=2, max=130)
    private String description;

    @NotNull
    private Double productValue;

    private String base64Hash;

    private String imageType;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean general;

    private Byte rank;

    private Long seedId;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean plantClimbs;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean spicy;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean teaPlant;

    private Set<String> keywords = new HashSet<>(); 

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @NotBlank
    private LocalizedStorefront localizedStorefront;

    public AffiliateLinkCreateDTO() {
    }

    public AffiliateLinkCreateDTO(String affiliateUrl, String title, String description, Double productValue, Boolean general, Byte rank, Long seedId, Boolean plantClimbs, Boolean spicy, Boolean teaPlant, Set<String> keywords) {
        this.affiliateUrl = affiliateUrl;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.productValue = productValue;
        this.general = general;
        this.rank = rank;
        this.seedId = seedId;
        this.plantClimbs = plantClimbs;
        this.spicy = spicy;
        this.teaPlant = teaPlant;
        this.keywords = keywords;
        this.localizedStorefront = localizedStorefront;
    }
```

And heres the `@Query` method again that i'm using for the retrieval:

```
@Repository
public interface AffiliateLinkDao extends JpaRepository<AffiliateLink, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT new DTOs.EntityDTOs.AffiliateLinkUpdateDTO(s.affiliateUrl, s.title, s.description, s.productValue, s.general, s.rank, s.seedId, s.plantClimbs, s.spicy, s.teaPlant, s.keywords) FROM AffiliateLink s WHERE s.id = :id")
    public AffiliateLinkUpdateDTO getAffiliateLinkDetailsById(@Param("id") long id);

}
```

EDIT:

When i reduce the constructor to just s.keywords like so:

```
@Query("SELECT new DTOs.EntityDTOs.AffiliateLinkUpdateDTO(s.keywords) FROM AffiliateLink s WHERE id = :id")
public AffiliateLinkUpdateDTO getAffiliateLinkDetailsById(@Param("id") long id);
```

I still get the same strange error

EDIT:

The fully generated SQL command that causes the error is:

```
2018-08-02 13:27:12.438 DEBUG 1228 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select affiliatel0_.affiliateUrl as col_0_0_, affiliatel0_.title as col_1_0_, affiliatel0_.description as col_2_0_, affiliatel0_.productValue as col_3_0_, affiliatel0_.general as col_4_0_, affiliatel0_.rank as col_5_0_, affiliatel0_.seedId as col_6_0_, affiliatel0_.plantClimbs as col_7_0_, affiliatel0_.spicy as col_8_0_, affiliatel0_.teaPlant as col_9_0_, . as col_10_0_, affiliatel0_.localizedStorefront as col_11_0_, affiliatel0_.id as col_12_0_, affiliatel0_.affiliateImageUrl as col_13_0_ from AffiliateLink affiliatel0_ inner join affiliate_keywords keywords1_ on affiliatel0_.id=keywords1_.id where affiliatel0_.id=?
```

Comment: That just looks like an alias for the table - the 'keywo' bit might not be the cause of the problem. It says syntax problem 'near'. One approach is turning on showsql, getting the full sql and running it against the database. Then you can remvoe parts and work out which bit mysql doesn't like by process of elimination.

Comment: @RyanDawson I rewrote the query and the constructors so the AffiliateLinkUpdateDTO now only retrieves the keywords set from AffiliateLink. This throws the same SQL syntax error! So the cause of the problem really is the ElementCollection keywords

Comment: I suspect it is about the use of the column name 'keywords' as the exception could match to one mentioned on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144230/how-to-specify-jpa-join-column-names but am not sure as you are using a basic type whereas they are not

Comment: Yeah https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075199/jpa-elementcollection-list-specify-join-column-name suggests the column name in the annotation should be singular rather than plural

Comment: Scratch that, presumably it's the absence of referencedColumnName in yours which is the problem

Comment: awwww i just finished renaming everything to `bananajelly`! Only to find out that indeed it solve the problem, i'm going to try and see if adding referenceColumnName makes any difference now

Comment: @RyanDawson adding `referencedColumnName` doesn't change a thing. This time i get the error: `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as col_0_0_ from AffiliateLink affiliatel0_ inner join banana_jelly bananajell1_' at line 1` This is really annoying.

Comment: this is the full SQL command made by Spring data `select . as col_0_0_ from AffiliateLink affiliatel0_ inner join banana_jelly bananajell1_ on affiliatel0_.id=bananajell1_.id where id=?`

Comment: yeah so I think that is a syntax error because it should be 'inner join <table_name>' and presumably banana_jelly is the column name.

Comment: Maybe try:

@ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
        name = "affiliate_keywords",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    @Column(name="keyword")
    private Set<String> keywords;

Comment: i changed everything to bananajelly just to find out if the name was to blame. Shouldn't it be @Column(name="keywords") with an s?

Comment: It's creating a table and mapping each value in the collection to a row in the table. So each entry in the column represents a single keyword. Like each entry is a color in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075199/jpa-elementcollection-list-specify-join-column-name

Comment: Actually I would expect it to work with @ElementCollection @CollectionTable( name = "affiliate_keywords", @Column(name="keyword") private Set<String> keywords;

Comment: when i change everything back to its former state and add your suggestions, it still throws the same old error

Comment: i think i should just use the findOne method of Spring data to get the actual AffiliateLink and then populate AffiliateLinkUpdateDTO in the java code itself… not a solution but a workaround i will have to settle with..

Comment: Yeah presumably a problem in the DTO part of the @Query with 's.keywords'. Perhaps you could change the @Query to do something like `FROM AffiliateLink s join s.keywords WHERE`. Not sure that would work though

Comment: Maybe you could use https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-map-native-query-results-pojo/ instead

Comment: thx for the link, i'll take a look