# JPA 2.0 Map<Integer, Entity>

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I would like to store a map with Integer,Entity but JPA is storing the entity inline so that means i get an error like that:

> A truncation error was encountered trying to shrink VARCHAR
>   '곭獲4捯洮瑨潭慳灥牯畴歡⹡汰瑩浩湧⹭潤敬⹈慲摷慲敆潯瑰物湴���Ȁౌ彰敲獩獴敮捥彦整捨䝲潵灴,䱯牧⽥捬楰獥⽰敲獩獴&' to
>   length 255..

How can i force JPA to only store the id of the entity?

EDIT:

```
@ElementCollection
private Map<Integer, Footprint> footprints = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Comment: Please add the code of your map to the question.

Comment: Already done. The Integer should represent the position of the footprint

Comment: By definition, an ElementCollection does not contain entities. An ElementCollection contains basic types, or embedded types. What you want is a OneToMany.

Comment: how to achieve a map with an onetomany collection?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that this isn't possible with an `@ElementCollection` but what you probably want is an unidirectional `@OneToMany` relationship.

If the Integer in your Map is really the ID of corresponding the Footprint entity, the Map construct would also be redundant.

Try something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Something {

  @Id
  @Column(name="SOME_ID")
  private long id;   

  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="SOMETHING_ID", referencedColumnName="SOME_ID")
  private List<Footprint> footprints = new LinkedList<>();

}
```

**See also:**

- [What is the difference between Unidirectional and Bidirectional associations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360795/what-is-the-difference-between-unidirectional-and-bidirectional-associations)
- [Difference between @OneToMany and @ElementCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969059/difference-between-onetomany-and-elementcollection)

Comment: thats good but i want to add an extra integer which isn´t the id of the entity. The table should have two properties: id of the footprint and an extra integer which is different.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your `Footprint` entity is defined as follows:

```
<!--language: java-->

    @Entity
    public class Footprint {
        @Id
        private String id;                 //PK of Footprint

        @ManyToOne                         //owning side of the relationship
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_something") //FK of Something
        private Something something;
    }
```

In general for mappings of type `Map<Basic, Entity>` the key can be modeled in two ways:

1. `@MapKeyColumn` annotation creates an additional column in Footprint entity (the owning side of the relationship) to store the map key

   ```
   @Entity
   public class Something {
       @Id
       private Integer id;

       @OneToMany(mappedBy = "something")   //non-owning side of the relationship
       @MapKeyColumn(name = "id_footprint") //specifies the map's key
       private Map<Integer, Footprint> footprints = new LinkedHashMap<>();
   }
   ```

   The above relationship will produce the corresponding database tables:

   ```
   Footprint
   --------------------
   id            int PK
   id_something  int FK
   id_footprint  int     <-- referenced by the map's key

   Something
   --------------------
   id            int PK
   ```
2. `@MapKey` annotation does NOT create additional column in Footprint entity (the owning side of the relationship) and the map key is stored as the part of the entity by referencing its primary key:

   ```
   @Entity
   public class Something {
       @Id
       private Integer id;

       @OneToMany(mappedBy = "something") //non-owning side of the relationship
       @MapKey(name = "id")               //refers to Footprint's primary key
       private Map<Integer, Footprint> footprints = new LinkedHashMap<>();
   }
   ```

   The above relationship will produce the corresponding database tables:

   ```
   Footprint
   --------------------
   id            int PK  <-- referenced by the map's key
   id_something  int FK

   Something
   --------------------
   id            int PK
   ```