# Does @ElementCollection imply orphanRemoval?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

According to this post [Difference between @OneToMany and @ElementCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969059/difference-between-onetomany-and-elementcollection) I should prefer `@ElementCollection` for embeddable types and `@OneToMany` for entities. But using `@OneToMany` I can  additionaly set option `orphanRemoval=true`. How can I do this with `@ElementCollection`? It it implied?

Answer (score 4):

It is implied. Removing the owning entity would also remove all data on the `@ElementCollection`. Setting the `Collection` to null or changing elements in the `Collection` would cause an update if `Session` isn't already closed.

The official documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-synopsis) says this:

> 2.8.1. Collections as a value type
>
> Value and embeddable type collections have a similar behavior as
> simple value types because they are automatically persisted when
> referenced by a persistent object and automatically deleted when
> unreferenced. If a collection is passed from one persistent object to
> another, its elements might be moved from one table to another.
>
> ...
>
> For collections of value types, JPA 2.0 defines the @ElementCollection
> annotation. The lifecycle of the value-type collection is entirely
> controlled by its owning entity.

I ran these three tests to test it out:

```
  @Test
  public void selectStudentAndSetBooksCollectionToNull() {
    Student student = studentDao.getById(3L);
    List<String> books = student.getBooks();

    books.forEach(System.out::println);

    student.setBooks(null);

    em.flush(); // delete from student_book where student_id = ?
  }

  @Test
  public void selectStudentAndAddBookInCollection() {
    Student student = studentDao.getById(3L);
    List<String> books = student.getBooks();

    books.add("PHP Book");

    books.forEach(System.out::println);

    em.flush(); // insert into student_book(student_id, book) values(?, ?)
  }

  @Test
  public void selectStudentAndChangeCollection() {
    Student student = studentDao.getById(3L);
    List<String> newBooks = new ArrayList<>();

    newBooks.add("Rocket Engineering");

    newBooks.forEach(System.out::println);

    student.setBooks(newBooks);

    em.flush(); // delete from student_book where student_id = ?
    // insert into student_book(student_id, book) values(?, ?)
  }
```

This is the `Student` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "student_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(
      name = "student_books",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "student_id"))
  @Column(name = "book")
  private List<String> books = new ArrayList<>();

  // Getters & Setters

}
```

Comment: But that's not orphanRemoval is all about. Of course if you remove parent, children will be removed in a cascade way, but what if you just lose reference (e.g. by setting it to null) to the child, so that it's not available anymore?

Comment: Yes, the `@ElementCollection` field implicitly has `Cascasde.ALL` + `orphanRemoval = true`

Comment: Using Hibernate 5.0.12.Final a constraint is created with no delete cascade