# How to map oneToone and OneToMany relationship between 3 entities?

Tags: java, jpa, entity

I am trying to program this relationship in JPA but seems to be lost in here.
This is my ER-model decription.
I have a `Customer`, which one have one `Depot` and this `Depot` contains shares(stocks).
So this is what I think.
Every `Customer` has a `Depot` that is (has relationship) 1:1 and a Depot can contain more Shares(stocks). Depot --> Shares (1:m)

I have the following code.

> Customer.java

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.getAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c") 
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 101L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id; //todo: for standard way of defining primary key

    @NotNull
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    private String lastName;


    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="depot_id", nullable=false, updatable=false)
    private Depot depot;


    public Customer() {
        super();
    }

}
```

> Depot.java

```
@Entity
public class Depot  implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 102L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    /*@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)*/
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Long id;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tdepot")
    private List<Share> lshares;

    //todo: Total estimated value in USD
    @Transient
    private BigDecimal totalValue = new BigDecimal(0.0);


    public Depot(){
        super();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        if(lshares == null){
            lshares = new ArrayList<>();
        }

    }
}
```

> Shares.java

```
@Entity
public class Share implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 103L;


    @Id
    protected String symbol;


    @NotNull
    protected String companyName;

    @NotNull
    protected Long floatShares;
    protected BigDecimal lastTradePrice;

    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private java.util.Date lastTradeTime;

    @NotNull
    protected String stockExchange;


    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="depot_id", nullable=false, updatable=false)
    private Depot tdepot;

    public Share(){
        super();
        lastTradeTime = new Date();
    }
}
```

With the above code I can even create and persist a Customer. Am I doing the mapping wrongly?

I am getting the following error message if I try to persist data into the above Database. [shorten for readibility]

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to
>   persist: net.dsfinance.bank.ejb.entity.Customer

```
With .merge instead of persist
```

> 12:48:48,875 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper]
>   (default task-46) SQL Error: 23502, SQLState: 23502 12:48:48,876 ERROR
>   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-46)
>   NULL not allowed for column "DEPOT_ID"; SQL statement: insert into
>   Customer (address, depot_id, firstName, lastName, password, role,
>   username, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-173] 12:48:48,883
>   INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl]
>   (default task-46) HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained
>   JDBC statements 12:48:48,888 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (default
>   task-46) ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed
>   for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffffc0a80869:-53b30100:5af571b4:4d,
>   org.jboss.as.txn.service.internal.tsr.JCAOrderedLastSynchronizationList@6806a37a
>
> > : javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
> >     execute statement     at
> >     org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(EntityManagerImpl.java:235)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2967)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:316)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:47)
> >       at
> >     org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:37)
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could
>   not execute statement     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2897)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3397)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:465)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2963)
>     ... 129 more Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not
>   allowed for column "DEPOT_ID"; SQL statement:

This was when i was using `entitymanger.persist()`, after googling, some people suggested that I should use `merge` but still didn't allow me to add customer into the database.

What do I want to achieve:
I want to create a database for a simple tradingservice java EE application with,
Customer having a Depot. Depot containing all the shares bought buy a specific Customer.
How do I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: depends on what you need; what's your problem anyway?

Comment: @HBo my problem is how to link the relationship between the entities correctly. so that i can persist data into the database. as of now I can't. running this on Jboss wildfly server.

Comment: I was thinking the relationship between Depot und Customer is wrong, 1:m instead of the 1:1. Because the Depot table should contain a lot of Depot shares information for different customers.

Comment: that's where the background is important (=your needs). For instance, if `depot` is not very important, you could map a collection of `shares` using and `@ElementCollection` annotation (just to avoid having to do customer.getDepot().getShares(). Why can't you run this? What exception, ...?

Comment: @HBo the ElementCollection sounds good. just to cut off the long way. But I don't know how to do that. Can you please provide a solution to make this simple. Customer and shares. Thanks.

Comment: ElementCollection is supposed to be only for 'simple' types (see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969059/difference-between-onetomany-and-elementcollection), not sure it would fit your needs because you'd have to 'choose' a column to collect inside `Shares` (lastTradePrice for example)

Comment: @HBo DN1, I updated my question now to be more specific. Thanks for your contribution. Please I am new to JPA and the whole Java EE thing. we patient with me.

Comment: @HBo I restarted the Server and posted the full error message in my question? Is there any work around this problem. I think is because of my wrong mapping.

Comment: in real world/normal bank a customer can have multiple depots ... and the relationship between share and depot should be a **many-to-many**!

Comment: ..(but with the current setup) in case of `persist`: you must persist the depot (id must be generated), before you persist the customer. in case of  `merge` ... (`updatebale= false` can be to blame) ...depot_id is null! (??)

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide the code you use to persist your entities, I won't elaborate on this (unless you edit your post) and I'm gonna focus on the steps to take care of such a problem.

First of all, try simple, then elaborate: remove your `depot` object from the `Customer` class to make sure that your Id generation strategy works properly. If not, you need to fix it first, depending on your database. You need to be able to persist a simple `Customer`.

Once you can persist a customer, add a `depot` to it (just like it is right now), without its `shares` collection. Same steps than before, until you can persist an Customer and its Depot.

Finally, add the `shares` collection, like it is right now. IMO, because I'm not familiar with the @PostConstruct annotation, I'd remove it and replace by a plain old collection initialization:

```
private List<Share> lshares = new ArrayList<>();
```

If none of the above works, it's clearly not a mapping problem anymore!

Comment: Thanks will give it a try.