# Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class for List<String> in Spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying Spring data jpa implementation using CrudRepository.
Below is my Entity Class

```
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id = null;

  @OneToMany
  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name="photoUrls")
  @Valid
  private List<String> photoUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  public List<String> getPhotoUrls() {
    return photoUrls;
  }

  public void setPhotoUrls(List<String> photoUrls) {
    this.photoUrls = photoUrls;
  }

}
```

And have a repository as below,

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{
  
}
```

And trying to use h2 database for local testing

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

And from the CommandLineRunner calling the save method of the UserRepository, but getting below error,

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: model.User.photoUrls[java.lang.String]
> at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1191) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
> at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:794) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969059/difference-between-onetomany-and-elementcollection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate supports three data mapping types: basic (e.g String, int), Embeddable and Entity. Most often, a database row is mapped to an Entity, each database column being associated to a basic attribute. Embeddable types are more common when combining several field mappings into a reusable group (the Embeddable being merged into the owning Entity mapping structure).

Both basic types and Embeddables can be associated to an Entity through the `@ElementCollection`, in a one-Entity-many-non-Entity relationship.

```
  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name="photoUrls",
                   joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name =  "user_id"))
  @Valid
  private List<String> photoUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
```

So you need to remove `@OneToMany` as OneToMany is for one-Entity-many-Entity relationship. If you want to map to an Entity, then need change the code like below and create a new Entity Photo.

```
@OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
private List<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<>();
```

In the above code , Photo is an Entity.

see the below link for more information:
https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-optimize-unidirectional-collections-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: @Pradeep accept this answer if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are **not** using Entity model for storing photo urls.

`@ElementCollection annotation is used to store a list of values as an entity attribute without needing to model an additional entity`.

So you need to remove @OneToMany.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToOne`, `@OneToOne` or `@ManyToMany` annotation unless there are  relationships between tables so remove `@OneToMany` since there is no relationship in your case.

```
public class User {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
      private Long id = null;
    
      @ElementCollection
      @CollectionTable(name="photoUrls")
      @Valid
      private List<String> photoUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
    
      public Long getId() {
        return id;
      }
    
      public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
      }
      public List<String> getPhotoUrls() {
        return photoUrls;
      }
    
      public void setPhotoUrls(List<String> photoUrls) {
        this.photoUrls = photoUrls;
      }
    
    }
```