# JPA child entity without primary key

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I have an Entity

```
@Entity
public class EntityA{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    //other columns
    -------
}
```

I am trying to create a child Entity without primary key

```
@Entity
public class EntityB{
    @ManyToOne
    private EntityA entityA;
    //other columns
    -------
}
```

But this is throwing error for primary key for EntityB.

Can anyone help here to make this relationship without primary key in child entity.

Comment: No can do. Every entity needs a primary key.

Comment: If `EntityB` does not have an identity, then by definition it is not an entity. Perhaps `@ElementCollection` is what you want

Comment: I think crizzis is right. Here's more info that may help you decide.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969059/difference-between-onetomany-and-elementcollection/8969169