# @ElementCollection over @OneToMany or vice-versa

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

Let's assume I do have an `Offer` entity. It has a property `salaries` that may be a list of `Salary` objects. The `Salary` cannot exist without an `Offer`, so does it mean I should use `@ElementCollection` or may not? When should we use `@ElementCollection` and when `@OneToMany`. The same question comes to my mind when we talk about `@Embeddable` and `@Embedded`, is it worth using it, or perhaps it's better to have a `@OneToOne` relationship.

```
class Salary(
    val salary_from: Integer,
    val salary_to: Integer,
    val salary_type: Type
)

class Offer(
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "offer_salaries", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "offer_id"))
    @OrderColumn
    @Column(name = "salaries")
    val salaries: List<Salary>;
)
```

Comment: ElementCollection is highly inefficient.

Comment: @Alien Why? Can you provide more details? Does it mean that `@Embeddable` and `@Embedded` are also inefficient and it's better to use `@OneToOne`?

Answer (score -1):

`@OneToMany` is meant for when you want to map to a db table as an entity.
`@ElementCollection`: you can look at it as a regular collection which is used for mapping non-entities.

ref: [Difference between @OneToMany and @ElementCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969059/difference-between-onetomany-and-elementcollection/8969169)

**E.G:** you have a `Perfume` entity and it has `2` lists.

- *scents* - is a list of attribues (should be `@ElementCollection`) since it contains some attributes which are not entities.
- *customers* - is a list of entities (should be `@oneToMany` since it should be mapped as an entity)