# Spring @CollectionTable updatable=false doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I need to map a list of IDs to my Entity. But I write these IDs to the database using native SQL (faster than hibernate), so I need to disable autosaving of @CollectionTable fields, but updatable=false not working. My mapping:

```
 @NotAudited
  @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @Column(name = "user_id",insertable = false,updatable = false)
  @CollectionTable(name = "crm_contact_list_user_included_items_ids",
          joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="contact_list_id",updatable = false,insertable = false)})
  protected Set<Long> userIncludedItemsIds = new HashSet<>();
```

Is there any way to do what I want ?

Comment: The limitations of using an ElementCollection instead of a OneToMany - is that the Embeddable objects cannot be queried, persisted, merged independently of their parent object. 
[Refer this link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969059/difference-between-onetomany-and-elementcollection)
[Refer this link 2](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection)

Comment: @ArunDuraisamy bad knews (.. Hibernate took 38 seconds to insert 18,000 IDs, whereas the native insertion process completed the task in just 0.5 seconds.

Comment: did you try one to many relationship with sqlinsert ? sample `@OneToMany(fetch = fetchtype.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="id")
@sqlinsert(sql = "insert into itemId (id) values (?)")
protected Set<ItemIds> itemsIds = new HashSet<>();`

Comment: @ArunDuraisamy I need to map exactly Set<Long>. Hibernate has bad performance and I want to write insertion queries myself as even native batched JDBC queries are very slow because rewriteSql param doesn't help to insert many records to the database fast. I found out that the only way to insert ~15k IDs into the database is to write a manual query that does it at once. It took only 500 ms, while native batched SQL with rewriteSql param enabled took 8 Seconds !!!. And without rewriteSql enabled it took 32 seconds.

Comment: In the Entity add method to remove UserIncludedItemsIds before persist or update. After insert you can run sql insert statement manually to insert/ update itemIds.
Select record will not get impacted. 
`@PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    void removeUserIncludedItemsIds() {
        this.userIncludedItemsIds = new HashSet<>(); 
    }`