# Hibernate Association Mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working with Hibernate.

RelationShip Details:

- One USER belongs to Many COMMUNITY
- One FACULTY can handle One COMMUNITY
- FACULTY is a USER

So here FACULTY is a weak entity and I need to create Faculty.java without any primary key attribute like:

```
private Integer facultyId;
```

and only with the fields

```
User user; Community community;
```

Is there a better way to approach rather than creating facultyId which is redudant here?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820897/jpa-entity-without-id

Comment: @Pradeep do you want me to put user and community properties within <composite-key> ?

Comment: here is some useful link in chech the 'No Primary Key' section    http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#No_Primary_Key

Answer (score 0):

Your relationship details are confusing me:

Practically thinking, **If One USER belongs to Many COMMUNITY, One COMMUNITY will definitely have Many USERS. Don't you think SO??** You got to re-think about this..

Still... Considering you defined relationship
As long as faculty has no other attributes assigned to it other than community.What I suggest is that instead of creating a separate table for faculty(which I think is not required) you can add extra column in COMMUNITY TABLE as COMMUNITY_ROLE and define role as FACULTY in it for required users.
Advantage:
Since USER-COMMUNITY are 1 to MANY in relationship, We will have user in COMMUNITY and COMMUNITY_ROLE will define the for FACULTY or NULL.

Still I strongly feel USER-COMMUNITY will be many to many, which will overthrow my workaround solution above which is based on you relationship details provided above which I think are wrong.