# Spring Data JPA entity with NO @ID/Primary Key

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot Data JPA. For few tables I don't need primary key.
How could I achieve that? Is it possible?

Comment: Depends on the use case. If you don't need them to map to entities, they don't need a primary key. It will be easier if you provide an example, though

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820897/jpa-entity-without-id  .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA entity without id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820897/jpa-entity-without-id)