# JPA Entity with partial columns for an Object using Java

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I have a table which is of kind Ledger which records all information with no unique values.

| Name | Date | Statement |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | random data |
| Second | row | random data |

I am trying to create an Entity which will only fetch name and statement

```
@Entity
public class MyTable {
  private String name;
  private String statement;

}
```

As I am not specifing @Id I am getting exception and We don't have any unique identifier in the table I can't mention @Id annotation.

Also, If we need to write any user defined method for getting these values please suggest how to do that as well.Any sources or samples will greatly help here.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but your SQL table really should have some sort of primary key in it.  Once you have it, just map it over to the Java entity and annotate it with `@Id`.

Answer (score -1):

As you don't have any unique identifier, you need to define that first.
You can do it in two ways:

1. Redesign the table and identify any column which is unique Or
2. Declare a Long value as a unique identifier like this[works for mysql, for pg, you need to define a sequence for auto `id` generation]:

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

Moreover, to get values, don't forget to add `getters` `setters` method for these fields.

Comment: The table can't be altered and if I include id which won't be available in the table and might cause different errors.

Comment: you can follow this whole thread or just this answer [JPA entity without id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3823596/5332914)

Comment: I followed this but am not sure what should we mention in JpaRepository<object, PKType> as we usually mention the Id Type here. Any sample working code can be of great help in understanding how to use it.

Comment: I am not sure but if your `Name` column is unique, you can annotate it as `@Id` and then mention String in your `JpaRepository<object, String>` like this.

Comment: As already mentioned nothing in the table are unique.

Comment: May be you missed this: **If your table has no unique columns at all, you can use all of the columns as the Id.**

Comment: Yup I tried this, Doing this made even worse as every column is now being treated as PK.