# Persistent entity '*******' should have primary key error in @Entity class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity, primary-key

When creating an @Entity mapping a table my IDE notifies me: `Persistent entity '*******' should have primary key`.

But the table in the DB doesn't have an ID (I think it's bad but it's legacy which I've no permissions to fix)

What should I do? Will it work if I just omit the ID field? Or should I make up an ID which is not mapped on the table but satisfy the code?

Comment: I guess that you can still somehow uniquely identify a record, either by a single column or by multiple columns? Either way, put `@Id` on every column that is required to uniquely identify a record

Comment: Just to add to @XtremeBaumer: The JPA ID annotation doesn't need to be on the table's primary key, it is just a convention as it is indexed and guaranteed to be unique. It should be unique, as it will be used for caching and object identity, so duplicates will cause a mess with what is returned from queries. IDs are also immutable; you cannot update the values and would have to delete and reinsert new instances to make changes to properties marked as IDs.

Answer (score 0):

**Every JPA entity must have a primary key.**
You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cmp30cfg001.htm#:%7E:text=Every%20JPA%20entity%20must%20have%20a%20primary%20key.).

From the Java Persistence book: Identity and Sequencing: [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#No_Primary_Key:%7E:text=If%20your%20object%20does%20not%20have%20an%20id%2C%20but%20its%20table%20does%2C%20this%20is%20fine.%20Make%20the%20object%20an%20Embeddable%20object%2C%20embeddable%20objects%20do%20not%20have%20ids.%20You%20will%20need%20a%20Entity%20that%20contains%20this%20Embeddable%20to%20persist%20and%20query%20it.)

> If your object does not have an id, but its table does, this is fine.
> Make the object an Embeddable object, embeddable objects do not have
> ids. You will need a Entity that contains this Embeddable to persist
> and query it.

Try also to read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820897/jpa-entity-without-id)

Comment: ok, what should I do? I cannot edit the table

Comment: You can create another Table(clone) with an Id to be used with the JPA Entity , and within the DB you can manage the copy past between the two tables using some triggers for example..

Comment: @J.J.Beam answer updated hope it will help

Comment: If the table does not provide an explicit id column, you can always annotate all fields with `@Id` effectively creating an composite primary key over all column. This way a record is unique by all fields, not just by an id column. That is in my opinion the better way