# How can I update the ID of a JPA entity?

Tags: java, jpa

Related to this [JPA entity without id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820897/jpa-entity-without-id)

Where I just want JPA to update a single record.  However I get

> identifier of an instance of mypackage.XyzClass was altered

How can I update the ID of a JPA entity?  Assuming it is possible

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: It's not. Altering a primary key is not allowed in SQL.